# How to set text-overflow ellpsis with dangerouslySetInnerHTML React?

Tags: css, reactjs, html-react-parser

I am trying to get the content saved as HTML tag and print it.
I set it to 'text-overflow : ellpsis' because I need only brief details, but it doesn't work.
Is there any workaround?

```
  const MyFeedList: IPost = MainData?.recentMyPostResponseList?.map((item: any) => {
    return (
      <div className="feed" key={item.id}>
        <img src={item.postImage} width="500px" />
        <h4>{item.postName}</h4>
        <h6
          style={{ overflow: "hidden", textOverflow: "ellipsis" }}
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: DOMPurify.sanitize(item.content),
          }}
        ></h6>
      </div>
    );
  });
```

[image]

Comment: Please show the rendered HTML. It could be because of the ginormous image you have in there; `text-overflow` only affects text, not images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
h6{           
    width:50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 1;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```